# How can I move child element to align with the right side of an outer div?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to use `text-align:right`, or `float:right` to align the `#submit_button` element to align with the right border of the `#outer_rim` div, but so far no luck.

How do I do that?

In short, I want the `Add Product` button to move to the right, instead of the left, where it is now.

**Code**

```css
<!-- #add_product_form span,

#product_fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}

#add_product_form label,
#submit_button {
  display: block
}

#add_product_form span {
  width: 530px
}

#submit_button {}
```

```html
<div id="outer_rim" style="display: inline-block;">
  <form action="" method="post" name="add_product_form" id="add_product_form">
    <fieldset id="product_fieldset">
      <legend>Product:</legend>
      <label><span>Some really really long description here</span>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1"></label>
      <label><span>Spare?</span>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Add&#x20;Product">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `float:right` is correct, you just need to wrap the button inside a div or add `display:block;` to `fieldset`

```css
<!-- #add_product_form span,
#category_fieldset,
#product_fieldset,
#product_type_fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}

#add_product_form label,
#submit_button {
  display: block
}

#add_product_form span {
  width: 530px
}

#product_fieldset {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

#submit_button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer_rim" style="display: inline-block;">
  <form action="" method="post" name="add_product_form" id="add_product_form">
    <fieldset id="product_fieldset">
      <legend>Product:</legend>
      <label><span>Some really really long description here</span>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1"></label>
      <label><span>Spare?</span>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1"></label>
    </fieldset>

    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Add&#x20;Product">

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: okay ..I can probably do that ..  but if the entire HTML is generated by a third party API library.. is there another way where I can do this using CSS only?

Comment: @Dennis you can do it with css by making fieldset a block element .. take a look at my answer

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code with the float:right into the CSS for the submit button the button is shifted to the right.  You might have forget to add in the ; after the display:block.  This would cause both lines to be read as one.

```css
<!-- #add_product_form span,
#category_fieldset,
#product_fieldset,
#product_type_fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}

#add_product_form label,
#submit_button {
  display: block;
  float:right;
}

#add_product_form span {
  width: 530px
}

#submit_button {}
```

```html
<div id="outer_rim" style="display: inline-block;">
  <form action="" method="post" name="add_product_form" id="add_product_form">
    <fieldset id="product_fieldset">
      <legend>Product:</legend>
      <label><span>Some really really long description here</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1"></label><label><span>Spare?</span>
    
                <input type="checkbox" value="1"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Add&#x20;Product">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this:

```css
<!-- #add_product_form span,
#category_fieldset,
#product_fieldset,
#product_type_fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}

#add_product_form label,
#submit_button {
  display: block;
  float:right;
}

#add_product_form span {
  width: 530px
}

#submit_button {}
```

```html
<div id="outer_rim" style="display: inline-block;">
  <form action="" method="post" name="add_product_form" id="add_product_form">
    <fieldset id="product_fieldset">
      <legend>Product:</legend>
      <label><span>Some really really long description here</span>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1"></label>
      <label><span>Spare?</span>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Add&#x20;Product">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Full page this and your answer breaks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are hard coding the width of the element above. The simplest answer is to hard code the margin-left of the button.

```css
<!-- #add_product_form span,
#category_fieldset,
#product_fieldset,
#product_type_fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}

#add_product_form label,
#submit_button {
  display: block
}

#add_product_form span {
  width: 530px
}

#submit_button {
    margin-left: 499px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer_rim" style="display: inline-block;">
  <form action="" method="post" name="add_product_form" id="add_product_form">
    <fieldset id="product_fieldset">
      <legend>Product:</legend>
      <label><span>Some really really long description here</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1"></label><label><span>Spare?</span>
    
                <input type="checkbox" value="1"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Add&#x20;Product">
  </form>
</div>
```